# How to redirect to an external URL with message when a link is clicked with jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I have a few links on a page that requires letting the user know that they are being redirected to an external source when they click a link. How do I intercept or display a message that says "You are being redirected to an external source" that stays for 5 seconds and then redirect the user to  URL in the clicked linked?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

above answer should display a confirmation dialouge, if you want to redirect after said time you would want to do something like this:

```
$('a.external').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.PopUpMessage').show();

    var redirect = setTimeout(function(){
        window.location.href = this.href;
    }, 5000);
});
```

where the '.PopUpMessage' contains your message and is hidden by default...

if you wanted to get fancy you could even count down the seconds... like

this HTML would be within your message

```
<p>You will be redirected in<span id="sec">5</span></p>
```

and place this JS within the link click function

```
var seconds = 5;
var count = setInterval (function(){
    seconds--;
    $('#sec').html(seconds);
}, 1000);
```

Comment: This countdown is something I really should do as well, thanks for all the great answers!

Answer (score 3):

Prevent the default action, pop up a confirm or a dialog with a setTimeout, and redirect programatically :

```
$('a.external').on('click', function(e) {
    return ( confirm('you are being redirected to ' + this.href) );
});
```

note that this is considered bad UX, and especially waiting for five seconds to be redirected would make most users just leave ?

Comment: +1 Rather than the prevent default, you could just `return` the `confirm()` directly.

Comment: @Orbling - that's a good point, as it returns true / false anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
  $("a").on("click",function(e) { // or use a class selector
    if (this.hostname!=location.hostname) {
      var URL = this.href;
      $("#redirectMessage").fadeIn("slow");
      setTimeout(function() { location.href =URL;},5000);
      e.preventDefault(); // stop link
    }
  });

});
```